# How call method from Qt GUI in background worker thread using QThread

Tags: c++, qt, qthread

I'm trying to add to my GUI in Qt code recieving data from vrpn server. And I need to continuously send data from this server to the application and call action(method) in interface when I receive some information.

But I have problem with endless cycle `while (running)`. I found that solution is use QThread for recieving data from server, but I can't figure out how use method from QT class in worker when I recieve some data from server.

I tried make worker this way, but I'm not sure, how to call method from another class when I recieve some data from server (or if it's at all possible/or exist better way):

```
#include "Worker.h"

#include <iostream>
#include "vrpn_Analog.h"


void VRPN_CALLBACK vrpn_analog_callback(void* user_data, vrpn_ANALOGCB analog)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < analog.num_channel; i++)
    {
        if (analog.channel[i] > 0)
        {                   
            THERE I WANT CALL METHOD nextImage(), which I have in QT class mainwindow
        }

    }
}

// --- CONSTRUCTOR ---
Worker::Worker() {

}

// --- DECONSTRUCTOR ---
Worker::~Worker() {

}

// --- PROCESS ---
// Start processing data.
void Worker::process() {

    /* flag used to stop the program execution */
    bool running = true;

    /* VRPN Analog object */
    vrpn_Analog_Remote* VRPNAnalog;

    /* Binding of the VRPN Analog to a callback */
    VRPNAnalog = new vrpn_Analog_Remote("openvibe_vrpn_analog@localhost");
    VRPNAnalog->register_change_handler(NULL, vrpn_analog_callback);

    /* The main loop of the program, each VRPN object must be called in order to process data */
    while (running)
    {
        VRPNAnalog->mainloop();
    }
}
```

I'm newbie in using QT so I'll be grateful for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Add a signal `callback` to Worker and pass the pointer to the register function (which will be passed as `user_data`).

```
void VRPN_CALLBACK vrpn_analog_callback(void* user_data, vrpn_ANALOGCB analog)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < analog.num_channel; i++)
    {
        if (analog.channel[i] > 0)
        {                   
            Worker* worker = std::reinterpret_cast<Worker>(user_data);
            worker ->callback(i, analog.channel[i]);
        }

    }
}

void Worker::process() {

    /* flag used to stop the program execution */
    bool running = true;

    /* VRPN Analog object */
    vrpn_Analog_Remote* VRPNAnalog;

    /* Binding of the VRPN Analog to a callback */
    VRPNAnalog = new vrpn_Analog_Remote("openvibe_vrpn_analog@localhost");
    VRPNAnalog->register_change_handler(this, vrpn_analog_callback);//add the pointer here

    /* The main loop of the program, each VRPN object must be called in order to process data */
    while (running)
    {
        VRPNAnalog->mainloop();
    }
}
```

Then you can connect the callback signal of Worker to whatever you want independent from your main window.

```
connect(worker, &Worker::callback, this, &MainWindow::nextImage);
```

Having said all that I suggest using a QTimer set to timeout 0 to call `VRPNAnalog->mainloop();` so the event loop of worker can run once in a while.

Answer (score 0):

> THERE I WANT CALL METHOD nextImage(), which I have in QT class mainwindow

You can use `QMetaObject::invokeMethod`:

```
QMetaObject::invokeMethod(mainwindow, "nextImage");
```